# Validation for shared component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a shared component for file upload to reuse it whenever needed. If I place my file upload code in same html of the form, the validation works. If i make that as separate component the validation isn't working.

Note: I want to use validation for file in some components and don't want to validation in other components

Here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfi-leupload-amq23e) of the code which I have tried

```
<form [formGroup]="formLocation" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitFarmLocation()">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label>Property Identification Number</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="propertyIdentificationNumber"
                            [class.invalid]="!formLocation.controls['propertyIdentificationNumber'].valid && formLocation.controls['propertyIdentificationNumber'].touched " >
            <div
                *ngIf="!formLocation.controls['propertyIdentificationNumber'].valid && (formLocation.controls['propertyIdentificationNumber'].touched || isSubmitted)">
                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">Please enter property identification
                    Number
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <app-sharedfile></app-sharedfile>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class=" ml-auto pb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? you want the file component to behave like a formControl? as if it was a subForm? you want the parent form validation to be updated when the file component's validity change?

Comment: @Teja Can you please check the solution added by me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of helper services and a simple Subject without doing much changes in your current code.

I have a service FileService which has a Subject which you can use in main component when user click on Save button.

```
export class FileService {
  checkFileUploadSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  setCheckFileUploadValidity() {
    this.checkFileUploadSubject.next(true);
  }

  checkFileUploadValidity(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkFileUploadSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In your main component, you can notify the shared component by calling next method on this FileService Subject instance.

```
app.component.ts
 onSubmitFarmLocation() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    this.isShowErrors = true;
    this.fileService.setCheckFileUploadValidity();
    if (this.formLocation.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(this.formLocation.value, this.formLocation.errors);
  }
```

Then you can listen to the events emitted by this Subject in your shared component and check for the errors by marking FormContrls as touched.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fileService.checkFileUploadValidity().subscribe(value => {
      debugger;
      this.formLocation.markAllAsTouched();
    });
  }
```

Please find the working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfi-leupload-xfpdfr

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have

```
@ViewChild(SharedfileComponent) child1Component: SharedfileComponent;
```

you just need to call the validation from there, so you can just use:

`this.child1Component.formFiles.invalid` or `this.child1Component.formFiles.valid`

so just add this in your `onSubmitFarmLocation` method:

```js
 onSubmitFarmLocation() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    this.isShowErrors = true;
    if (this.formLocation.invalid ) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.child1Component.formFiles.invalid) {
      console.log('form file invalid');
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.formLocation.value, this.formLocation.errors)
  
  }
```

**update:**

if you want to display error messages in shared component,
first, you used isSubmitted in your html but not in your ts, so it wont never display.
the tricky part is make `onSubmitFarmLocation()` to return a boolean, and depends on it if the submit can continue or not.

sharedfile.component.ts

```js
onSubmitFarmLocation(): Boolean {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    return this.formLocation.valid;  
  }
```

and in your component, during submit use it like:

```js
onSubmitFarmLocation() {
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  this.isShowErrors = true;
  this.child1Component.onSubmitFarmLocation();
   
  if (this.formLocation.invalid ) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.child1Component.formLocation.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(this.formLocation.value, this.formLocation.errors)
}
```

updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfi-leupload-hvlegz

Comment: I tried that, but error message is not displaying. I want to display error message like other fields if it's not valid.

Comment: I'm not able check error in stackBlitz too. Can you please check it?

Comment: @sai Ah that's because when the main form is invalid , the upload form will not be checked. I updated the answer, now we should always check the upload form.

Comment: You are near. But the validation should be inside the main form. not inside shared one. Because there is no need of validation in some pages

Comment: you should explain all theses info in your thread. For solution, pass as @Input if you need a validation or not and depend on it you can add a conditional validation